# Can you use __init__ in a SQLAlchemy Base object to self-initialize?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have

```
class Book(Base):
    isbn = Column(String(50), primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(20))

    def __init__(self, isbn):
        self = session.query(Book).filter(Book.isbn==isbn).first()

foo = Book("isbn info here")
```

This doesn't work, but I can't seem to find supporting documentation on how I could allow for an **init** function to load an object. It would be less verbose than

harryPotterBook = session.query(Book).filter(Book.isbn=='random isbn info here').first() to look up a book everytime

Thank you

Comment: Two issues: you can't assign to `self` usefully, and you aren't calling `Base.__init__`, which may be necessary. You might want to define `__new__` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you misunderstand the way SQLAlchemy generates an object from database query.

The following is copied from the document of SQLAlchemy:
The SQLAlchemy ORM does not call __ init __ when recreating objects from database rows. The ORM’s process is somewhat akin to the Python standard library’s pickle module, invoking the low level __ new __ method and then quietly restoring attributes directly on the instance rather than calling __ init __.

__ init __ is used when you want to create a plain old object